# Database results into 3 equal columns

Tags: php

I've got a very minor problem but it's one I'd like to work out, so I'm looking for suggestions.

I'm using the following PHP code to echo the data from an array.

```
$array = array();
$rsa = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from wp_letter ORDER BY l_name ASC");
foreach($rsa as $rrr)
{
array_push($array,$rrr->l_name);
}
$temp = 0;
foreach($array as $as)
{
$temp = 0;
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_term_taxonomy AS tx, wp_terms AS trm WHERE taxonomy = 'category' AND  trm.term_id = tx.term_id  AND name like '".$as."_%' ORDER BY name ASC");
foreach($query as $row1)
{
if($temp == 0)
{
echo '<h4>'. $as.'</h4>';
$temp = 1;
}
?>
<a class="anchor" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_category_link($row1->term_id)); ?>"><?php echo $row1->name;?></a><br/>
<?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: ..so what's the question here?

Comment: I want result into 3 Equal  column ..http://charitram.com/ I want this type 3 column

Comment: What is the current generated HTML code? What do you want the generated HTML code to be?

Comment: simple use <h4></h4> tag and <a></a>...

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `LIMIT 3` into your Query, e.g.

```
SELECT * from wp_letter LIMIT 3 ORDER BY l_name ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use some crap like (for example):

```
$query = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];    
$results = ['1col' => [], '2col' => [], '3col' => []];
foreach($query as $key => $result) {
    if (($key+1) % 2 === 0 && !(($key + 1) % 3 === 0)) {
        $results['2col'][] = $result;
    } elseif (($key+1) % 3 === 0) {
        $results['3col'][] = $result;
    } else {
        $results['1col'][] = $result;
    }

}
```

OR just smth like this:

```
$results = array_chunk($query, ceil(count($query)/3));
```

Links:
[array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)
[ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)